# Bug with @AllArgsConstructor in Lombok?

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

I have the following error when starting my spring boot application:

*Parameter 17 of constructor in be.mypackage.dataimport.soft99.transformers.visit.VisitTransformer required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.*

I am using @AllArgsConstructor on VisitTransformer but I also have a private String variable for that class defined. It's just a String so now he assumes it should be a bean for the constructor and gives the above error.

This code used to work but as of last friday 2023-10-6 doesn't anymore. I looked at the changelog of lombok but didn't find anything specific related to this so I'm wondering whether they unknowingly introduced a bug?

(P.S.: The fix is to just not use @AllArgsConstructor anymore and define the constructor yourself.)

Comment: Does a downgrade help? If no, it might be something else

Comment: @Sam I downgraded to version 1.18.22 and it does have the same issue which indeed suggests it's something else. I have no clue what though. I can't find anything that changed on project scale but I will investigate further.

Comment: Please include the code of `VisitTransformer`. If this is an `@Component` (or one of the specific ones) the generated constructor will be used to create an instance and when that happens all parameters need to be available as beans as well. The best fix, don't use Lombok ;).

Comment: @M.Deinum, VisitTransformer is annotated with @ Service but I have found what's going on. Apparently the private String variable was added to the VisitTransformer last friday and lombok always regards it as should be a bean injected by the constructor when using AllArgsConstructor. Never in the project that happened before apparently. If you make the variable static (which in this case is possible), the problem is resolved. Not using lombok works too :)

Comment: It has not to do with Lombok taking this is, it is Spring. Lombok only does what you instructed it to do, generate a constructor for all fields in the class. Also are you really sure the field can be `static` as it feels like shared state. I would discourage the use of `@AllArgsConstructor` and make the fields needed for DI all `final` and use the `@RequiredArgsConstructor` instead. Or ditch Lombok all together and write your own constructors (it isn't that hard and saves you from these kinds of surprises).

Comment: "Lombok only does what you instructed it to do, generate a constructor for all fields in the class" --> so lombok takes it indeed, so it has to do with that ;) I wrongly assumed there were some rules for fields it takes or didn't take. Yes I am sure the field can be static, the code it impacts is only executed ever by one instance. However I did not make it static and just don't use @AllArgsConstructor anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `java docs` of annotation(`@AllArgsConstructor`) it create a constructor for all class fields

> Generates an all-args constructor. An all-args constructor requires
> one argument for every field in the class.

**Lombok**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

**Delombok**

```
public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Employee(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age= age;
    }
}
```

And I think this `Parameter 17 of constructor` was added by you and now you can not create the `@Service` or `@Component`. Usually in this case you can use Lombok but with another annotation `@RequiredArgsConstructor`(it is usually used when create a constructor injection in Spring Component without create a plain constructor).

> Generates a constructor with required arguments. Required arguments
> are final fields and fields with constraints such as @NonNull.

**Lombok**

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Employee {

    private final String name;
    private int age;
}
```

**Delombok**

```
public class Employee {

    private final String name;
    private int age;

    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

It is going to help you. also why to use `@RequiredArgsConstructor` because usually all fields into Spring Component that is another Spring Component is declared as `private final`

Comment: You are completely right. I just answered another comment that apparently that extra field was added last friday (when the error started occuring). I wasn't aware of that intitially :) Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I upvoted this one and deleted my question due to duplication. Thanks @Andei Lisa